# Styling not applied to DataTable in angular component

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-components

I have an angular component with the **JS DataTable** within it.

The html for the component is similar to this:

```
<h3>Test</h3>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" #table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column.name}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I have a css file for the component:

```
h3 {
  color: blue;
}

.paginate_button {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

Any styling I add for the table isn't applied but the styling for the h3 is!

If I add the `.paginate_button` style to the global **styles.css** the style is applied.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where exactly are you applying the `paginate_button` CSS Class in your Template?

Comment: It is part of the rendered datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS DataTable** is a component in itself which has it's own css file, that's why the style you overwrite in your component css file is not getting reflected. However, if we write some style in global styles.css, it is applied in all the component automatically.

Class `paginate_button` isn't present in your component's template. It is actually present in `JS DataTable`'s compoent. So the style cannot be change. Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

You can try this in global style.css:

```
.paginate_button {
  padding: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it makes no difference.

Comment: I thought so. It wont, you cannot change a style of one component from another component. The only way is global style.css